# Calendar software similar to iCal in Mac OSX for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, calendar, calendar.app

I have seen [iCal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICal) in Mac OS X, and it seems to be a great software to keep the track of tasks assigned and set reminders. Do a similar application exist Windows (offline)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Microsoft's Outlook](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/) for that purpose. As an open source alternative, there is Mozilla's [Sunbird](http://www.mozilla.org/projects/calendar/sunbird/).

Comment: thanks!.. but i need a offline software. I don't want to open outlook if i need to create a task

Comment: @romilnagrani: First, you can use Outlook offline; you don't have to be online. Second, you need to run a program (at least in the background) to be able to use it. So I don't understand why you don't want to open a program while you do want to use it.

Comment: would it be fine if i keep sunbird close but pin into taskbar?

Comment: @romilnagrani: I haven't used Sunbird (I've been using Outlook) but as far as I can tell, it needs to be open or at least be run in the background somehow. Maybe you can minimize it to system tray. I'm not sure, though.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at [VueMinder Calendar](http://www.vueminder.com)? It runs in the background and its main window can be accessed via an icon in the task tray. It also has a very nice semi-transparent desktop calendar that sits on your Windows desktop (and can be hidden if you don't want to see it).

I've found it to be far superior to Outlook, Sunbird, and everything else I've tried. It's a truly elegant piece of software and a joy to use.

Comment: Its cool... Many customization options... Best: minimize to tray and desktop alert reminder..

Answer (score 0):

I quite like [Rainlendar](http://rainlendar.en.softonic.com/).

> Rainlendar is a lightweight and customizable calendar for your desktop.
>
> [image]
>
> Rainlendar stands out from classic calendar programs thanks to a
>   highly customizable interface and the possibility to quickly and
>   effortlessly jot down notes and important events. Although it only
>   comes with two different skins, the program offers a link to
>   www.customize.org, where you should find the style which suits your
>   tastes. But Rainlendar doesn’t stop there. You can set up hotkeys to
>   manage Rainlendar at the push of a key and, thanks to various plug-ins
>   present in the program, integrate Rainlendar directly to other
>   utilities like Outlook and iCalendar. Rainlendar is always within
>   reach as a tray icon on your desktop and bringing it up just takes a
>   click of your mouse.   Unfortunately Rainlendar’s real originality is
>   also its weakness. The program offers a wide range of skins but adding
>   these to the program is far from straightforward. You have to drag
>   your downloaded skin into the Skins folder for the Rainlendar program
>   file and then browse to the new skin from the ‘Edit Skin’ option in
>   Rainlendar’s drop down menu.   If you like to keep your calendar on
>   your PC, but find the one offered by Windows too dull, Rainlendar is a
>   good alternative. You’ll enjoy setting your own style and the way it
>   discreetly fits onto your desktop.

Comment: Please expand this answer. Link only answers may be deleted.